# Compare 2 Columns values in 2 ExcelSheet

Tags: excel, compare

I want to compare two columns in excel 2 sheets
In sheet A Column is Gender with Numeric Value
And in sheet B Column is Gender with Alpha Value

```
A Gender      B Gender
----------------------
    1            M
    2            F
    2            F
    1            M
    2            M
    1            F
```

Here 1 = M and 2 = F.

If A Gender is 1 and B Gender is M then correct.
If A Gender is 1 and B Gender is F then Wrong.

How to Compare the Value in Excel?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Gender data starts from `A2` and goes down, type the following formula in `C2`:

```
=IF(OR(AND(A2=1,B2="M"),AND(A2=2,B2="F")),"OK","WRONG")
```

and autofill down as required.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative formula which might be easier to understand (and extend values if needs be)...

```
=CHOOSE(A2,"M","F")=B2
```

This formula basically reevaluates column A to be "M" when 1 and "F" when 2.  Then asks if that equals Column B, and you get a TRUE/FALSE return ;)

If you have a third value for 3, just add another comma separated value onto the end of the `CHOOSE` function.